# QLabel take full size into QToolBar

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt5, qtgui

I want to put `QLabel` into `QToolBar`. I do that but the `QLabel` changes `QToolBar` size, and does not fill it, see the first image below. What I need is make `QLabel` fill the `QToolBar` and resize the image, to be the same size as `QLabel` and `QToolBar`.

[image: http://s10.postimg.org/62xos6hi1/pic_In_Bar.jpg]

screenshot of what I want to happening:
 [image: http://s2.postimg.org/3xsvtc5bd/pic_In_Bar1.jpg]

I'm working with Qt 5.1, MinGw 4.8, and image type is *.gif*.

Comment: It is not very clear from your question what you need and what is your problem. Putting some code and/or screenshots will be very helpfull

Comment: I add image link in main post.

Comment: may be screenshot of what you want and what is happening, will help

Comment: this screenshot for real time but I need to make QLabel take full size into QToolBar and the same with QImage and in re-size the image re-size automatic.

Comment: @AmrEisa I edited your question a bit, based on how I understood it. Please check and correct if I misunderstood something.

Comment: @hyde, thanks :), sorry for my bad English. and for all too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you must to use `QLabel`? Perhaps you should set the background image using Qt style sheets.

Link to [customizing QToolBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbar).

Comment: this work for static Image I have gif Movie image. What I need is what border-image: url(:ImageInfo.ico); done but StyleSheet not working with animation gif file.

Comment: m_SoftImageLab = new QLabel( this );
QSizePolicy sizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Maximum );
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch( 0 );
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch( 0 );
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth( m_SoftImageLab->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth() );
m_SoftImageLab->setSizePolicy( sizePolicy );
m_SoftImageLab->setFrameStyle( QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken );
QMovie *movie = new QMovie( ":/new/Data/Image/EiSa.gif" );
m_SoftImageLab->setMovie( movie );
movie->start();
ui->m_ImageTbar->addWidget( m_SoftImageLab );

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for but I think it will do the job.

Comment: If it is important, and you find no other way to do it, there's always the option of subclassing QToolBar and seeing if you can do some custom painting (not sure if it would work, but I'm thinking of overriding `paintEvent`, drawing your own background, then calling superclass paintEvent to draw the rest). Or just writing your own toolbar widget from scracth, either on top of `QWidget` or using QML.